# json to mysql inserting only last record

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

i am trying to insert JSON to MYSQL database, i have successfully accessing each element of json, but my code is inserting only the last record of json, here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Store");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

  $filename = "employee_data.json";
 $json = file_get_contents($filename);
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);


    foreach($obj as $item) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (barcodeNumber,name,catName) VALUES ('".$item['name']."', '".$item['designation']."', '".$item['gender']."') ";

echo $item['name'];
    }

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

as you see in my code, i can print every name of json, but it is inserting only last one!

And the json file
employee_data.json:

```
[  
   {  
     "name": "Michael Bruce",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "System Architect"  
   },  
   {  
     "name": "Jennifer Winters",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Senior Programmer"  
   },  
   {  
     "name": "Donna Fox",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Office Manager"  
   },  
   {  
     "name": "Howard Hatfield",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Customer Support"  
   },  
   {  
     "name": "Kevin Sanders",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Food service worker"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Fay K. Whitney",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Bookbinder"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Heather Hernandez",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Corporate recruiter" 

   },
   {  
     "name": "Rhonda Okelley",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Image designer"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Sandy Jacobsen",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Publicity agent"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Marisa Williams",  
     "gender": "Female",  
     "designation": "Molder"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Neil Simmons",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Engine and other machine assembler"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Raymond Lara",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Clerical assistant"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "William Carpenter",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Broker"  
   },
   {  
     "name": "Ted Baer",  
     "gender": "Male",  
     "designation": "Conservation worker"  
   }
 ]
```

it is inserting only the last record:

```
 {  
         "name": "Ted Baer",  
         "gender": "Male",  
         "designation": "Conservation worker"  
       }
```

Any help?

Comment: You call `mysqli_query(..)` outside the loop. Thus only the last query is executed. BTW: One can see that much easier, if you format your code properly.

Comment: Have a look at prepared statements for performance (mysql parse the SQL statement only once) and security ("sql injection", imagine adding a `O'Connor`)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are inserting the records after the loop. try this code:

```
foreach($obj as $item) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (barcodeNumber,name,catName) VALUES ('".$item['name']."', '".$item['designation']."', '".$item['gender']."') ";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Better approach is instead inserting each record in a lop use bulk insert:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO product (barcodeNumber,name,catName) VALUES "

foreach($obj as $item) {
    $query_values[] = "('".$item["name"]."', '".$item["designation"]."', '".$item["gender"]."')";
}

// Implode the query values array with a coma and execute the query.
$db->query($query . implode(',',$query_values));
```

Comment: Please use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php when using variables as strings in a query.